# Disallow "justify" with HTML-Filter

Tags: html, plone, filtering

On my Plone (4.2) Site, I have several users who regularly paste in texts from Word or OpenOffice. These texts are sometimes aligned as "justify", whereas I would not like to allow justified text blocks on the site (because it looks ugly).

Under the "HTML Filter settings" of the Plone Control Center, it does not seem to be possible to disallow a certain html attribute setting -- one can allow match  and tag attributes. I would like to disallow all `<xxx align="justify">` while still allowing elements to be right-aligned with `<xxx align="right">`.

Is there any way to do HTML filtering based on attributes' values in Plone?

Answer (score 3):

You could disallow the attribute align in Plone's html filter. Then the default align is used which is "left".

Nowadays the most common way to align a text is to use css: . The css property "text-align" could also be disallowed in that html filter. Please don't forget to remove "justify" button from the tinyMCE toolbar.

Comment: 'Then the default align is used which is "right".' ==> Don't you mean "left" here?